# Implementing SVM RBF

Tags: python, svm

I am new to the Data Science field and I know how to use sklearn library and how to customize the RBF kernel but I want to implement SVM-RBF kernel from scratch for learning purposes and how to implement fit and predict manually without using sklearn library.

Are there any good resources that help me? What skills do I need to learn to achieve this? 
Do you recommend any books that are easy and simple to understand the main concepts in machine learning for beginners as a start point?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi. sklearn SVM-RBF (or SVC-RBF) is using libsvm. The paper is available [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf). You'd need to have some knowledge in linear algebra. If you know c++, you can also check the implementation code [here](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm)

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Yes, I have some background in Linear Algebra and I keep reading in this area. I want to implement svm-rbf in python not in c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of SVM is often implemented with the SMO algorithm.
You may want check for the original published version (Platt, John. *Fast Training of Support Vector Machines using Sequential Minimal Optimization*, in Advances in Kernel Methods  Support Vector Learning, B. Scholkopf, C. Burges, A. Smola, eds., MIT Press (1998)), but it is quite complicated as for me.

A bit simplified version is presented in [Stanford Lecture Notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials/smo.pdf), but derivation of all the formulas should be found somewhere else (e.g. [this random notes I found on the Internet](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/ch9/node9.html)).

As an alternative I can propose you my own variation of the SMO algorithm.
It is highly simplified, implementation contains a bit more than 30 lines of code

```py
class SVM:
  def __init__(self, kernel='linear', C=10000.0, max_iter=100000, degree=3, gamma=1):
    self.kernel = {'poly':lambda x,y: np.dot(x, y.T)**degree,
                   'rbf':lambda x,y:np.exp(-gamma*np.sum((y-x[:,np.newaxis])**2,axis=-1)),
                   'linear':lambda x,y: np.dot(x, y.T)}[kernel]
    self.C = C
    self.max_iter = max_iter

  def restrict_to_square(self, t, v0, u):
    t = (np.clip(v0 + t*u, 0, self.C) - v0)[1]/u[1]
    return (np.clip(v0 + t*u, 0, self.C) - v0)[0]/u[0]

  def fit(self, X, y):
    self.X = X.copy()
    self.y = y * 2 - 1
    self.lambdas = np.zeros_like(self.y, dtype=float)
    self.K = self.kernel(self.X, self.X) * self.y[:,np.newaxis] * self.y
    
    for _ in range(self.max_iter):
      for idxM in range(len(self.lambdas)):
        idxL = np.random.randint(0, len(self.lambdas))
        Q = self.K[[[idxM, idxM], [idxL, idxL]], [[idxM, idxL], [idxM, idxL]]]
        v0 = self.lambdas[[idxM, idxL]]
        k0 = 1 - np.sum(self.lambdas * self.K[[idxM, idxL]], axis=1)
        u = np.array([-self.y[idxL], self.y[idxM]])
        t_max = np.dot(k0, u) / (np.dot(np.dot(Q, u), u) + 1E-15)
        self.lambdas[[idxM, idxL]] = v0 + u * self.restrict_to_square(t_max, v0, u)
    
    idx, = np.nonzero(self.lambdas > 1E-15)
    self.b = np.sum((1.0-np.sum(self.K[idx]*self.lambdas, axis=1))*self.y[idx])/len(idx)
  
  def decision_function(self, X):
    return np.sum(self.kernel(X, self.X) * self.y * self.lambdas, axis=1) + self.b
```

In simple cases it works not much worth than sklearn.svm.SVC, comparison shown below
[image]

I have posted this code with some more code producing images for comparison on [GitHub](https://github.com/fbeilstein/simplest_smo_ever).
For more elaborate explanation with formulas you may want to refer to [my preprint on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344460740_Yet_more_simple_SMO_algorithm).

**UPDATE:** now live version is available, see [Github Pages](https://fbeilstein.github.io/simplest_smo_ever/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It will be a good start to learn about SVM.